# Há algum jeito de escrever esse código de forma mais didática?

Tags: php

Basicamente o código faz um loop pelo banco buscando postagens, porém ele só postará caso a data agendada seja menor ou igual a data do momento. Ele busca pelo banco todas as postagens e lista, porém as que estão agendadas, ele não mostrará. E quando não há postagens agendadas ou não há nada no banco, ele diz que não tem postagens.

Ali tem dois elses. Daí vem a pergunta: Há como usar apenas um?

Tentei de várias formas e não consigo. Um else é para quando não há nada no banco, já o outro para quando não há postagens agendadas. Um else não reconhece o outro. Gostaria de um else apenas.

```
<div class="container">
    <% var valor = "No posts!"; %>

    <% if(noticias.length > 0) { %>
        <% for(var i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) { %>
            <% if(noticias[i].publicacao_agendada <= moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]H:mm')) { %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="noticia_wrapper">
                        <%= noticias[i].publicacao_agendada %>
                        <span class="noticia_autor"><%=noticias[i].autor%></span>
                        <a href="noticia?id_noticia=<%= noticias[i].id_noticia %>" class="noticia_titulo"><%=noticias[i].titulo%></a>
                        <span class="noticia_data"><%= moment(noticias[i].data_noticia).format(data) %></span>
                        <br />
                        <p class="noticia_resumo">
                            <%=noticias[i].noticia%>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% } else { %>
                <h1><%= valor %></h1>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
    <% } else { %>
                <h1><%= valor %></h1>
        <% } %>
</div>
```

Para facilitar a compreensão, eu, @LeoCaracciolo, coloquei algo mais simples

```
if(noticias.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) {
        if(noticias[i].publicacao_agendada <= moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]H:mm')) { 

        } else {

        }
    }
} else {

}
```

Comment: Por que tantas tags? Afinal, sua dúvida é com PHP, JavaScript, Java, C# e Node.JS?

Comment: Isso aí definitivamente não é php.....

Comment: O `if` interno parece estar errado, porque diria que não tem *posts* em cada um que não atende a condição? Acho que deveria procurar saber o que significa a palavra didática, ela não cabe neste contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que assim melhora um pouco:

```
<div class="container">
<% 
var valor = "No posts!";

if (noticias.length <= 0) 
{
%>
    <h1><%= valor %></h1>
<%
} else {
    for(var i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) {
        if (noticias[i].publicacao_agendada <= moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]H:mm'))
        {
        %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="noticia_wrapper">
                        <%= noticias[i].publicacao_agendada %>
                        <span class="noticia_autor"><%=noticias[i].autor%></span>
                        <a href="noticia?id_noticia=<%= noticias[i].id_noticia %>" class="noticia_titulo"><%=noticias[i].titulo%></a>
                        <span class="noticia_data"><%= moment(noticias[i].data_noticia).format(data) %></span>
                        <br />
                        <p class="noticia_resumo"><%=noticias[i].noticia%></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <%
        }
        else
        {
        %>
            <h1><%= valor %></h1>
        <%   
        }
    }
} 
%>
```

O que eu fiz foi basicamente inverter o primeiro if, jogando o maior código pro final e tornando mais legível, e usei as chaves no mesmo nível, o que facilita a utilização das tags (porém acho que não é a convenção correta do PHP).

Este código aparenta ser de um template para renderização de html no PHP, onde geralmente vc não consegue fugir muito da bagunça de tags.
Agora se esse não é um código só pra gerar html, aconselho você desacoplar controle de visão e separar esta estrutura em métodos, o que facilita muito a leitura.

Veja:

- [MVC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC)
- [CleanCode](https://bulldogjob.pl/articles/469-3-basic-rules-of-clean-code) Seção 2. Extract Method